# BootStrap twitch embbeded player to use entire parent's width

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, twitch

I'm new to website developement. I'm trying to get my embbeded twitch player to use it's parent full width. The height seems so work just fine, but whilst using the d-flex class from bootstrap it makes the player extremly thin.

Please watch my code here:
https://jsfiddle.net/Sagan_owl/nwvt2ag8/3/

Don't mind the player error message, that's expected

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Brams 225</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://embed.twitch.tv/embed/v1.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <main class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row corps">
            <div class="col-lg-2 bg-warning">
                <ul class="nav flex-column">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Bio</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Donations</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Professionnel</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-10 d-flex flex-column">
                <div class="row d-flex align-items-stretch section2-haut bg-success">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 d-flex align-self-center justify-content-center">
                        <div id="twitch-embed"></div>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            new Twitch.Embed("twitch-embed", {
                                width: "100%",
                                height: "100%",
                                channel: "monstercat",
                                // only needed if your site is also embedded on embed.example.com and othersite.example.com 
                                parent: ["embed.example.com", "othersite.example.com"]
                            });
                        </script>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row section2-bas bg-info ">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 mt-auto text-center">
                        <img src="https://panels-images.twitch.tv/panel-18340583-image-9eaaa5a0-b00a-4475-bc6a-c6b5930bae48"
                            class="img-fluid" alt="twitter img not found">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 mt-auto text-center">
                        <img src="https://panels-images.twitch.tv/panel-18340583-image-1deed596-2b7e-4781-9628-e3a82b4cc9c2"
                            class="img-fluid" alt="twitter img not found">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 mt-auto text-center">
                        <img src="https://panels-images.twitch.tv/panel-18340583-image-f0ce67ba-5a55-4aa6-8d94-b628ebac530a"
                            class="img-fluid" alt="twitter img not found">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>

</body>

</html>


----------

    main{
    height: 100vh;
} 

.corps{
    height: 100vh;
}

.section2-haut{
    height: 80vh;
}

.section2-bas{
     height: 20vh;
}
```

Comment: add `flex: 1;` for child

Comment: @s.kuznetsov That worked!!! I didn't knew this existed, i'll read about how it works.

Comment: I'm very glad it worked. Good coding.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the dimensions on the parent div

https://jsfiddle.net/pu5rhtxo/

```
#twitch-embed {
  width: 100%;
}
```

In this example I set some CSS on the parent Div

Also fixed the parent in the JS script tags so the player actually worked